# How to use Zend ProgressBar in a Zend MVC application

Tags: zend-framework, progress-bar

I've been trying to use the JsPush Zend progress bar in a Zend MVC application, but have not been successful.  I've used the JsPush.php example found on github to create a standalone progress bar test application, but this does not use the Zend MVC framework.  When I apply the CSS, HTML, JavaScript, and PHP code from the JsPush example program, I see my progress bar appear (the CSS works) but I don't get any results during my socket write process.  I've used the JsPush CSS code verbatim in a css file that is linked to my application so I won't repeat that here. Below are exerpts from my MVC application, the controller code:

```
protected function _sendFile($job)
{
    $fp = fopen($job->source_file, "rb");
    if($fp == null || $fileData['size'] == 0) {
        $this->view->errorMessage = 'Error - file open failed for ' . $job->source_file;
        return false;
    }

    $this->totalXmitSize = $fileSize;
    $this->currentXmitSize = 0;
    $progressMessage = '';

    $adapter = new Zend_ProgressBar_Adapter_JsPush(array
        ('updateMethodName' => 'Zend_ProgressBar_Update',
         'finishMethodName' => 'Zend_ProgressBar_Finish'));
    $progressBar = new Zend_ProgressBar($adapter, 0, $this->totalXmitSize);

    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $blkSize = ($fileSize > 1024) ? 1024 : $fileSize;
        $xmitBuf = fread($fp, $blkSize);

        if($xmitBuf === false || !strlen($xmitBuf)) {
            $this->view->errorMessage = 'Error - file open failed for ' . $job->source_file;
            return false;
        }

        if($this->_writeData($xmitBuf, $blkSize) == false) {
            return false;
        }

        $fileSize -= $blkSize;
        $this->currentXmitSize += $blkSize;
        $progress = $this->_calculateXmitProgress();

        if($progress < 25) {
            $progressMessage = 'Just beginning';
        } elseif($progress < 50) {
            $progressMessage = 'less than half done';
        } elseif($progress < 75) {
            $progressMessage = 'more than half done';
        } else {
            $progressMessage = 'almost done';
        }

        $progressBar->update($this->currentXmitSize, $progressMessage);

        if($fileSize <= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
    $xmitBuf = '';
    $bufLen = 0;

    if($this->_readData($xmitBuf, $bufLen) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $progressBar->finish();
    if(strncmp($xmitBuf, MSG_STATUS_OK, strlen(MSG_STATUS_OK)) != 0) {
        $this->view->errorMessage = 'Error - invalid response after file transfer complete';
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The view code:

```
<?php
$this->title = "My Title";
$this->headTitle($this->title);
$this->layout()->bodyScripts = 'onload="startProgress();"';
?>
<p class="errors"> <?php echo $this->errorMessage ?> </p >
<?php echo $this->form->setAction($this->url());
?>

<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="pg-progressbar">
        <div class="pg-progress" id="pg-percent">
            <div class="pg-progressstyle"></div>
            <div class="pg-invertedtext" id="pg-text-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pg-text" id="pg-text-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="progressBar"><div id="progressDone"></div></div>
```

The layout.phtml code:

```
function startProgress()
{
    var iFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iFrame);
    iFrame.src = 'MyController.php';
}

function Zend_ProgressBar_Update(data)
{
    document.getElementById('pg-percent').style.width = data.percent + '%';
    document.getElementById('pg-text-1').innerHTML = data.text;
    document.getElementById('pg-text-2').innerHTML = data.text;
}

function Zend_ProgressBar_Finish()
{
    document.getElementById('pg-percent').style.width = '100%';
    document.getElementById('pg-text-1').innerHTML = 'done';
    document.getElementById('pg-text-2').innerHTML = 'done';
}
</script>

</head>
<body <?php echo $this->layout()->bodyScripts ?>>
<div>
    <h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></h1>
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
</div>
```

When this runs I get a ton of JavaScript in the page source, but no progress results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">parent.Zend_ProgressBar_Update({"current":0,"max":3397,"percent":0,"timeTaken":0,"timeRemaining":null,"text":null});</script><br />
<script type="text/javascript">parent.Zend_ProgressBar_Update({"current":1024,"max":3397,"percent":30.14424492199,"timeTaken":0,"timeRemaining":0,"text":"less than half done"});</script><br />                                                                              
<script type="text/javascript">parent.Zend_ProgressBar_Update({"current":2048,"max":3397,"percent":60.28848984398,"timeTaken":0,"timeRemaining":0,"text":"more than half done"});</script><br />
<script type="text/javascript">parent.Zend_ProgressBar_Update({"current":3072,"max":3397,"percent":90.43273476597,"timeTaken":0,"timeRemaining":0,"text":"almost done"});</script><br />
<script type="text/javascript">parent.Zend_ProgressBar_Update({"current":3397,"max":3397,"percent":100,"timeTaken":0,"timeRemaining":0,"text":"almost done"});</script><br />
<script type="text/javascript">parent.Zend_ProgressBar_Finish();</script><br />
```

All of this JavaScript pushes my form out of view.  I have spent days on the Zend documentation site and scouring the web to find examples of someone successfully using Zend ProgressBar in a MVC framework application, but can not find any working examples.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have been successful in getting a JsPush progress bar to work *to some degree*, but not 100% correct for my application.

The progressbar works, but the form results end up in the hidden iframe. There is no way to get to the submit buttons on that iframe, so my user has to use the back button to get out of the form.

The only way to get the progress bar to work is to use the target attribute in the form and assign it to the name attribute of the iframe.  If I don't use the target attribute, the form scrolls for every call to `progressBar->update;`. So my form results end up on the parent page several hundred lines scrolled down and the scroll bar never works.

I've tried using the example from the Zend documentation, but it doesn't work.  This is my first venture into the Zend framework and it has been very frustrating and disappointing.  Not a single response to my original question from 28 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. For me it worked since I did the following steps.
Go to the php.ini and check if the following Data is set in your php.ini.

- output_buffering = Off
- ;output_handler =
- zlib.output_compression = Off
- ;zlib.output_handler =

Then go to class Zend_ProgressBar_Adapter_JsPush and find the Method - which is at the bottom - _outputData. Delete everything in this Method and input

```
// 1024 padding is required for Safari, while 256 padding is required
    // for Internet Explorer. The <br /> is required so Safari actually
    // executes the <script />
    echo str_pad($data . '', 1024, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT) . "\n";

    echo(str_repeat(' ',256));
    if (ob_get_length()){
        @ob_flush();
        @flush();
        @ob_end_flush();
    }
    @ob_start();
```